# Why can't grouped class name resolve correctly for frontend_model?

Tags: system.xml

I have a frontend model set to a grouped class name of `module/system_config_readonlyRenderer`, however I receive this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Module_Block_System_Config_ReadonlyRenderer'`

However, setting the class name directly to `Package_Module_Block_System_Config_ReadonlyRenderer` works.

The file `ReadonlyRenderer.php` exists within `Package/Module/Block/System/Config` too.

Whats going wrong here with this grouped class name?

Comment: can you post the config.xml file of your module?

Comment: most probably you are missing the `<models>` declaration.

Comment: Close, I was missing a `<blocks>` declaration.  If you submit an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing this declaration within my `config.xml` file, which resolved the issue:

```
<blocks>
    <module>
        <class>Package_Module_Block</class>
    </module>
</blocks>
```

I guess without it, Magento does not know where to resolve the grouped class name properly.